Is woocommerce_product_get_weight filter hook deprecated?
I'm using the following PHP code in WooCommerce to hide product details on single product pages from customers, as the numbers are only for shipment calculations and aren't accurate measurements for the products:
// hide weight etc from additional information
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_weight', 'hide_single_product_dimensions', 25, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_width', 'hide_single_product_dimensions', 25, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_height', 'hide_single_product_dimensions', 25, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_length', 'hide_single_product_dimensions', 25, 2 );
function hide_single_product_dimensions( $value, $product ){
    // Only on single product pages
    if( is_product() )
        $value = '';

    return $value;
} 

The code works, but another dev recently told me that woocommerce_product_get_weight (and the other 3) are deprecated, and that I should replace them.
I looked at the WooCommerce Code Reference, specifically the class-wc-deprecated-filter-hooks.php. From what I could gather, 'woocommerce_product_get_weight' is the replacement of the deprecated 'woocommerce_product_weight'. I can't find anything on 'woocommerce_product_get_weight' itself being deprecated. I have extensively googled it as well, but as I am a beginner, I may have used incorrect search terms.
Does anyone know if this filter is or isn't deprecated? (If so, with what was it replaced?)
TL;DR is 'woocommerce_product_get_weight' a deprecated filter hook?

No there are not deprecated!. This is a valid composite hook based on WC_Product get_weight() method, so you can't find it WooCommerce Code Reference. Same thing for the other hooks.

@LoicTheAztec Thank you so much for your quick answer!

All those hooks have 2 arguments, the first one is the returned value, and the 2nd one is the Product object. For product variation replace "product" from the hook string with "product_variation" like woocommerce_product_variation_get_weight.

@LoicTheAztec Thanks for the addition of that, but my question was purely about it being deprecated or not. I have no issues with product variations or such. :) I'll have a further look at composite hooks though.

The structure for those composite filter hooks is based on WC_Data get_hook_prefix() method used in WC_Data get_prop() method like: $value = apply_filters( $this->get_hook_prefix() . $prop, $value, $this ); (see it line 884), where $prop is the product property used in the related WC_Product getter method (like "weight"), $value is the returned value and $this the object (here the product object).
